# Test method Error, LIST has no rows

Tags: apex, code-coverage

In My custom Controller I have a below code

```
 @AuraEnabled
    public static ID saveEnrollment(Enrollment__c  accRec, String type ){
string uid = userinfo.getUserId();           
 Contact con=[SELECT Id, AccountId, Name FROM Contact WHERE User__c =:uid limit 1];
  accountId = con.AccountId;
    contactId =con.Id;

 Enrollment__c newEnrollment = new  Enrollment__c (               
                emitcs1__User__c = accountId,
                emitcs1__Enrollment_Type__c = type                
            ); 
            insert newEnrollment; 
}
```

Based on the `userinfo.getUserId()` i will be getting the logged in User and query the value in contact object and get the `con.AccountId` and insert the value in custom object.

Since I'm running the test class from admin login, which this user doesn't have value data in my system, So test code fails.

Can you please, help me how to bypass or cover the code for this kind of scenario.

Comment: You have to create COntact and all corresponding data in test context. Proper test should not rely on actual dataa

Comment: I can create a new test data for User, But how we can assign  current user to the created User.

Comment: You will need to create an User associated a Contact and use RunAs feature. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm